# How add an optional many to many relationship to another many to many relation table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, many-to-many, database-normalization

I've got the following tables defined:

```
- Group
  - GroupID (pk - int)
  - ...

- Item
  - ItemID (pk - int)
  - ...

- Groups_Items
  - GroupID (pk - int)
  - ItemID (pk - int)
```

There is a FK on the GroupID linked to the Group table and there is one on the ItemID which is linked to the Item table.

I need to add an optional relationship to the Groups_Items table i.e. RuleSetId

```
- Groups_Items
  - GroupId (pk - int)
  - ItemId (pk - int)
  - RuleSetId (int - nullable)
```

With the Ruleset table defined as follows:

```
- RuleSet
  - RuleSetId (int)
  - RuleId (int)
```

and the Rule table is defined as follows:

```
- Rule
  - RuleId (int)
  - ...
```

When I try to add an FK using the RuleSetId from the RuleSet table to the RuleSetId from the Groups_Items table, it's giving me an error telling me I'm not allowed.

Each Item must be associated to a group, and a group can have multiple items but I want to provide the option to allow one or more rules to be associated to an item via a RuleSet. Note that I don't want to associate the ruleset directly to the item itself but to the item associated to the group as the item could be the same but associated to different groups and a different set of rules may apply depending on the group the item belongs to.

I hope this makes sense.

I'm struggling to get this to work so I must be designing this incorrectly but I'm not sure how best to approach this.

**Update - 1**

Here's the diagram of what I'm trying to achieve. Note that I've added the RuleSet table in the meantime which just contains a primary key i.e. RuleSetId

[image]

I'm getting the following error when I try to add a relationship between the GroupsItems table and the RuleSet table:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_GroupsItems.ERuleSet". The conflict occurred in database 
"MyDatabase", table "dbo.RuleSet", column 'RuleSetId'.
```

and I'm getting the following error when I try to add a relationship between the RuleSet table and the RuleSetRules table:

```
Unable to create relationship 'FK_RuleSetsRules.RuleSet'.
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_RuleSetsRules.RuleSet". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", 
table "dbo.RuleSet", column 'RuleSetId.
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, **chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.**

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @ philipx - Just to be clear, there was no code to give since I was using SQL Server diagram to generate my relationships. I listed the tables with the relevant keys and foreign keys and I explained what the issue was as best as I could. @Seanb clearly understood my problem and came back with a suggestion & code that worked but I've since added the diagram of what I wanted to achieve and the specific errors that occured. Anyway, Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: The content of an ERD can be given as text, which text is called DDL, which is also part of implementation code. My comments don't come from not understanding your problem, they come from site protocols & wanting to help you get an answer. Notice that the answer has a pile of comments & edits arising from lack of question clarity & information. PS Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Note that in this answer, I have changed the meaning of your 'ruleset' table. In this answer, the Ruleset table creates each ruleset (but not the rules). RulesetID is an int and PK. Then rules are linked to this ruleset in Ruleset_Rules.

---

I believe the Ruleset table also needs to have a primary key that is referenced by the foreign key. I suggest Ruleset and Rules also get a many-to-many table linking them (if you want to re-use rules) or have RulesetID as a field in rules. This example has the many-to-many:

```
CREATE TABLE Grp (GroupID int PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE Item (ItemID int PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE RuleSet(RulesetID int PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE Rules(RuleID int PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE TABLE RuleSet_Rules (RulesetID int, RuleID int, PRIMARY KEY (RulesetID, RuleID))
CREATE TABLE Grp_Item (GroupID int, ItemID int, RuleSetID int, PRIMARY KEY (GroupId, ItemId))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Grp_Item] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Grp_Item_Grp] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Grp] ([GroupID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Grp_Item] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Grp_Item_Item] FOREIGN KEY([ItemID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ItemID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Grp_Item] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Grp_Item_Ruleset] FOREIGN KEY([RulesetID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RuleSet] ([RulesetID])
GO
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a67b0699912f193e634c974a7841b8f) with setup and example inserts.

UPDATE: Here's an [updated DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5857d1e62e2d96b78342c32120ac1b6b) from comments below. This has more FKs as well as explaining that some inserts deliberately fail.

Note this assumes that each combination of group/item can have either 0 or 1 ruleset assigned to it. If you need to have more than one ruleset, it becomes a little more complex in the many-to-many table for Grp_Item.

Also note I haven't created all FKs - just the ones relevant to the current problem in Grp_Item.

Comment: I did exactly this and just spotted your reply i.e. introduce a RuleSet table which just has a RuleSetId but for some reason, it's failing if I'm trying to add a relationship between it and the RuleSet_Rules or between the Groups_Items table. I'll try your scripts in a second instead of the Database Diagram and see how I get on.

Comment: I've added a diagram which highlight what I'm trying to achieve. Note that I've ran your db<>fiddle, and I'm getting an error. "Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Grp_Item_Ruleset". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_86fe7f407ef641139e4a0af2508ff927", table "dbo.RuleSet", column 'RulesetID'.
Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 2
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Sorry yes - I wasn't explicit. That one was designed to fail as there is no Ruleset_ID 99 (showing that the FK constraint is working).

Comment: Still not working. I've updated my question btw with a diagram. It is what you are suggesting, isn't it?

Comment: @Thierry - your database diagram appears to be correct. If it was me in your situation, I'd be guessing I've put a FK the wrong way around (again) (sigh). Anyway, I made a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5857d1e62e2d96b78342c32120ac1b6b) with more FKs and data showing issues. Is that doing what you want?

Comment: @Thierry - Something to check - I believe the only FKs here should be on the two many-to-many tables? You may also have rogue FKs hanging around from previous attempts . I suggest taking a backup of tables/FKs (either script or database backup), remove all FKs, then recreate them one by one.

Comment: Hi Sean, you're not going to believe this but what you suggested and what I changed was right all along!! I stupidly left some test data in the table (single row in both my RuleSet and Rule tables) which caused the errors to occur! Really bad error if you ask me but look, I'll remember this the next time it happens! Hopefully it won't :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> With the Ruleset table defined as follows:
>
> ```
> - RuleSet
>   - RuleSetId (int)
>   - RuleId (int)
> ```
>
> and the Rule table is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> - Rule
>   - RuleId (int)
>   - ...
> ```
>
> When I try to add an FK using the RuleSetId from the RuleSet table to
> the RuleSetId from the Groups_Items table, it's giving me an error
> telling me I'm not allowed.
>
> Note that I don't want to associate the ruleset directly to the item
> itself but to the item associated to the group as the item could be
> the same but associated to different groups and a different set of
> rules may apply depending on the group the item belongs to.

By adding the RuleSetId to the Groups_Items table there is an explicit association between RuleSet and Items, which is what you don't want.  Currently, the RuleSet table only contains a primary key and RuleId, it's missing GroupId. I think you're looking for something like this:

With the Ruleset table defined as follows:

```
- RuleSet
  - RuleSetId (pk - int)
  - GroupID (fk - int)
  - RuleId (fk - int)
```

and the Rule table is defined as follows:

```
- Rule
  - RuleId (pk - int)
  - ...
```

Now the RuleSet table contains the relationships between GroupId's and RuleId's therefore there isn't a reason to add RuleSetId to the Groups_Items table.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but wouldn't what you suggested make the RuleSet be associated just with the Group rather than the Group & Item which is what I need. For example, I could have 2 groups i.e. Private & Public and one item called "first name" and I want to apply a min len on it, but the "first name" requires 5 chars while the public may require 7 chars. I could have a third-group called Personal which also uses the "first name" and doesn't require any rule to be applied. Is this making sense?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to start from scratch. Use *editor* to create DDL (schema).

```
-- Rule RUL exists.
--
rule {RUL}
  PK {RUL}
```

```
-- Rule set RST exists.
--
rset {RST}
  PK {RST}
```

```
-- Rule RUL is member of rule set RST.
--
rule_rset {RST, RUL}
       PK {RST, RUL}

FK1 {RST} REFERENCES rset {RST}
FK2 {RUL} REFERENCES rule {RUL}
```

```
-- Item ITM exists.
--
item {ITM}
  PK {ITM}
```

```
-- Group GRP exists.
--
group {GRP}
   PK {GRP}
```

```
-- Item ITM is member of group GRP.
--
item_group {GRP, ITM}
        PK {GRP, ITM}

FK1 {ITM} REFERENCES item  {ITM}
FK2 {GRP} REFERENCES group {GRP}
```

```
-- Set of rules RST applies to item ITM in group GRP.
--
item_group_rset {GRP, ITM, RST}
             PK {GRP, ITM}

FK1 {GRP, ITM} REFERENCES item_group {GRP, ITM}

FK2 {RST} REFERENCES rset {RST}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```